How to filter Supabase JSONB with Bash
How would I filter using .contain to filter by JSONB data in my GET request?
My JSONB follows this structure:
[
  {
    "service": "Babysitter",
    "available": true
  },
  {
    "service": "Pick-up or Drop-off",
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "service": "Nanny",
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "service": "Part-time daycare",
    "available": false
  },
  {
    "service": "Full-time daycare",
    "available": false
  }
]

I want to create a filter to say 'When [0].available = true '
I've tried
{Database}.supabase.co/rest/v1/accounts?careType=contains.available.true
but I honestly how no cluw how to work with the arrays or multiple values in my requests.

This: jq -r 'foreach .[] as $i ([]; if $i.available == true then $i.service else empty end)' ?

See: ths answer
